# CMD + tab not working between apps

Tags: macos

I recently upgraded to OS 10.8, and now when I try to switch between apps using command + tab the quick switch menu (not sure what its called) to the app after toggling to it, but it never actually switches over.  I then have to click on the app in the dock.  I tried looking in the keyboard menu, what is causing this?

Comment: Go to your Finder "Go" menu hold the option key and choose Library. Then go to Preferences folder and trash this file:
com.apple.finder.plist
Then, restart, or log out and in again.

(You may have to reset a few finder prefs the way you like them.)

Comment: Hi,I looked and do not have this file.  Any other things I can try?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the Dock is the process responsible for running the application switcher. It might help to remove the Dock preferences (~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Dock.plist), and log out/in. However, this may require you to repopulate your Dock with the current Applications and settings.